# Convert string to datetime in Powershell using ParseExact

Tags: string, powershell, csv, datetime

I have a Csv file with 3 strings for DateTime.

```
Date;
202202230930;
202202220815;
202202220612;
```

Because I have to use the Date for naming Snapshots on Proxmox i cant use the - sign. I wanna convert these Dates in to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

Now i wanna create a datetime variable in Powershell using that csv file. With the format 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm'

I created a foreach so for each date it will ParseExact the string into a datetime.

```
    $datesnapshot = import-csv -Path "D:\autosnap\Datetime.csv" -Delimiter ";"

    Foreach($Date in $datesnapshot){
        [datetime]::ParseExact($datesnapshot, 'yyyyMMddHH:mm', $null).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
    }
```

I get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." I don't know where the problem is because i typed in the Date it is expected to parse and the date i wanna receive. I hope somebody can help.

Kind regards

Comment: Please post your code _as plain text_, not screenshots (neither of which appear to be of your code btw)

Comment: You're giving `ParseExact` the collection `$datesnapshot` and not the item `$Date` as argument. Among other things

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note, the first one:

```sh
[datetime]::ParseExact($datesnapshot...
```

You're iterating over the collection `$datesnapshot` but also you're giving `ParseExact` the same collection as argument, it should be `$date` (the item) instead. In addition, your CSV generates an array of objects (`object[]`), where each object has a property with name **`Date`**. If you want to reference the value of your objects you should be using **`$date.Date`**. See [about_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.2#property-values) for more info.

Lastly, the format you're `yyyyMMddHH:mm` using will not correctly parse your dates. The format you should use is `yyyyMMddHHmm`.

```sh
$datesnapshot = @'
Date;
202202230930;
202202220815;
202202220612;
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

foreach($Date in $datesnapshot){
    [datetime]::ParseExact($Date.Date, 'yyyyMMddHHmm', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, iam new to powershell and have to learn a lot of things.